# Проблема с выводом текста на HTML и CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Написал код. Проверял, ошибок вроде как не нашел, но проблема в том, что текст, который должен быть выравнен по центру уходит то выше, то в бок

```css
header {
 background: black no-repeat center top / cover;
 height: 100vh;
}

body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #222222;
}

div {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
 content:'';
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
}

.container {
 width: 930px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
 margin-top: 76px;
 float: center;
}

nav {
 float: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu {
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 margin-top: 47px;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu li {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 41px;
}

.menu li a {
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 22px;
}

h1 {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 53px;
 text-align: center;
}

h3 {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 43px;
}

.titles {
 padding-top: 115px;
}

.titles_first {
 font-size: 27px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.title h1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}

.title h3 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
    background: #378dcc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-clip: padding;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff!important;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #49D4BC;
    margin: 40px;
}

.services {
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;

}
.services li {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 109px;

}
.servicees li p {
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 22px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Elena</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/boom.css">
</head>

<body>
 <header>
   <div class="container">
   <div class="heading clearfix">
    
    <img src="img/Elena.png" alt="Elena" class="logo">
  
    <div>
     <nav>
     <ul class="menu">
      <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>

      <li>
      <a href="#">Features</a>
      </li>

      <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
     </ul>

    </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="titles">
    <div class="titles_fisrt">
     <h1>HAVE A GOOD DAY</h1>

        <h3>JUST FOR YOU ON THEMEFOREST</h3>

      </div> 
    </div>

   <button class="btn">
    <span calss="arrow"></span>
    <span>GET YOUR COPY NOW</span>
    
   </button>

    </header>
    
    <section  id class="services">
     <div class="container">
      <ul class="services">
      <li>
      <p>Professionals</p>
      </li>

      <li>
      <p>Amateurs</p>
      </li>

      <li>
      <p>For Everyone</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
      
     </div>
     
    </section>
    
    <footer>
    
 </footer>
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить в каком именно месте страницы у вас проблема?

Comment: У вас в коде есть `float: center` для блока `nav`, это не работает, а флоату можно задавать только `right, left, none, inherit` http://htmlbook.ru/css/float. Напишите, что именно у вас выравнивается не по центру?

Comment: Выложил скрин. на нем как раз меню (ниже от логотипа) ушло в сторону и кнопка там же

Comment: Выложил скрин. на нем как раз меню (ниже от логотипа) ушло в сторону и кнопка там же

Comment: Если у вас есть какие-то вопросы, можете написать в комментариях под моим ответом, если вы считаете, что мой ответ вам помог, ответьте его как ответ(слева от вопроса, где репутация)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я написал по новому всё, но если есть вопросы, можете задать, тут можно всё легко в любую сторону засунуть

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: white;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1000px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 40px;
}

.intro {
 background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1500);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -ms-background-position: center;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: black;
}

.intro::before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.675);
 z-index: -1;
}

.intro__container {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 padding: 60px 0;
}

.intro__logo {
 font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
 font-size: 60px;
}

.menu {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.menu__item {
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu__item:not(:last-child) {
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu__item a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.menu__item a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.intro__text {
 margin: 80px 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.intro__title, .intro__subtitle, .button {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.intro__title {
 font-size: 44px;
}

.intro__subtitle {
 font-size: 16px;
}

.button {
 display: block;
 background-color: #4ad4bb;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 transition: .3s box-shadow ease-in-out,
    .3s -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out,
    .3s -moz-box-shadow ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgba(74,212,187,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0 15px 2px rgba(74,212,187,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgba(74,212,187,1);
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
 
 .container {
  padding: 0 10px;
 }

 .intro__title {
  font-size: 9vw;
 }
 
 .intro__subtitle {
  font-size: 4vw;
 }

 .button {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 6vw;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="intro">
 <div class="container"> 
  <div class="intro__container">
   
   <div class="intro__logo">
    Elena
   </div>

   <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item"><a>Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a>Services</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a>Features</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a>Contact</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div class="intro__text">
    <h1 class="intro__title">
     Have a good day
    </h1>
    <h3 class="intro__subtitle">
     just for you on themeforest
    </h3>
   </div>

   <a class="button">
    Get your copy now
   </a> 

  </div> <!-- .intro__container -->
 </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- .intro -->

</body>
</html>
```